# How to make class in C#, that can be cast to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, packing

How can I make class, that can be cast to DateTime. But I need to cast my class, when it packed. For example:

```
object date1 = new MyDateTime();
DateTime date2 = (DateTime)date1;
```

I need directly this working example.

I know how to do it, but my way will work without packing. I'm not sure is there way to do it.

Please, help.

PS. I need cast directly object to DateTime. So, MyDateTime have to be packed before. Explicit works well, but it doesn't help if you have packed object. And it have to cast just using ordinary casting like

```
(DateTime) (object) MyDateTime
```

Comment: As described, this is impossible. You can't use `Convert.ToDateTime`? Why does it need to be an `object` variable?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you appear to be after is inheritance, being able to "store" a derived class instance in a variable of the base type like so:

```
Stream s = new FileStream();
```

The fact that it is a `FileStream` under the hood is not lost just because you are pointing to it with the `Stream` goggles on.

`DateTime` is a `struct`, and `struct` inheritance is not supported - so this is ***not*** possible.

**An alternative** is the `explicit` keyword for [user-defined conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) (syntactically *looking* like casts). This allows you to at least interchange between your class and `DateTime` with more sugar.

This could look like:

```
class MyDateTime
{
    private DateTime _inner;

    public static explicit operator DateTime(MyDateTime mdt)
    {
        return mdt._inner;
    }
}
```

You can do the same with the counterpart `implicit` keyword:

```
public static implicit operator DateTime(MyDateTime mdt)
{
    return mdt._inner;
}
```

That then lets you do the "casting" implicitly:

```
DateTime date = new MyDateTime();
```

**Another alternative** is to wrap `DateTime` with your own adapter class that internally uses a `DateTime` and then inherit from this class to create `MyDateTime`. Then instead of using `DateTime` in your code base, you use this adapter class.

I've seen similar things with `SmartDateTime` style classes where the `DateTime` has a better understanding of nulls and if it was set.

Comment: @EvgenyEkim What you are looking for is inheritance then, if you want to store a derived type in a reference of a base type. This is not possible with `DateTime` as it is a `struct`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I don't know is there way to do it without inheritance.

Comment: @EvgenyEkim You can store a `DateTime` in your own class, but you cannot store your own class in a `DateTime`. I have demonstrated the former.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read all answer. Thank you very much for answer.

Answer (score 10):

You could use

```
class MyDateTime
{
    public static explicit operator DateTime(MyDateTime dt)
    {
        return new DateTime(); // Convert dt here            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a direct cast, I would create an extension method that performs the required steps to complete the conversion. Some sort of conversion is necessary, because DateTime can't be inherited from, so a direct cast will be impossible.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static MyDateTime ToMyDateTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
        //conversion logic
        return myDataTime;
    }
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this MyDateTime mdt)
    {
        //conversion logic
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

In this way, you would use the code like so:

```
DateTime dt = mdt.ToDateTime();
```

or

```
MyDateTime mdt = dt.ToMyDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write an explicit cast operator on your MyDateTime class that calls into one of the constructors on Datetime. [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).