# Converting from type OsacbmTime to type DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am implementing a project using the [OSA-CBM 3.3](http://www.mimosa.org/?q=resources/specs/osa-cbm-330) standard.  Within that standard, there includes a type called `Osacbmtime`.  I am attempting to parse a `DateTime` value from type `Osacbmtime`.  Casting doesn't seem to get the job done.  Is there a useful (or obvious) approach I can take to accomplish this?

Comment: add DateTime tag on your question, and you'll get Skeet here like a call to batman

Comment: @payo: Was already looking :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make class in C#, that can be cast to DateTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121630/how-to-make-class-in-c-that-can-be-cast-to-datetime)

Comment: I'd rather not register and subscribe just to get hold of an SDK or API documentation - is there any *public* documentation around this? What members does `Osacbmtime` expose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this snippet from [some Java code](http://www.koders.com/java/fid5F26CDDA00A20B45AA065B0BCFBBBAAB26BBD208.aspx?s=197#L133) (virtual the only reference I could find):

```
DMPort d = new DMPort();
d.lastUpdate = new OsacbmTime();
d.lastUpdate.time = "2007-08-15T16:23:09";
d.lastUpdate.time_type = OsacbmTimeType.OSACBM_TIME_MIMOSA;
```

I *suspect* you want something like:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(time.Time, "s",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Where `s` is the format specifier for the [sortable 8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable).

Answer (score 1):

`Osacbmtime` must be a custom library, because Google searches for it yield nothing.

Your best bet, with what little information you have provided about the `Osacbmtime` type, is to see if it is possible to output it in a date/time format, then parse it into a DateTime object, i.e.

```
DateTime myDT = DateTime.Parse(myOSACBMTime.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AA"));
```

Obviously this is pseudocode since I don't have the documentation for `Osacbmtime`, but (hopefully) you get the general idea.